# authorized_keys file did not save well, can't access my server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I edited the authorized_keys file on my server, while i was saving the file my internet connection died, and it did not save the file well.
Now i can't access my machine with the keys I have (the old one and the new one).
How can I fix it?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged it amazon-web-services, i would suggest to shut down the server, create a new one and attach the EBS from the old one. Then you can mount it and add the correct keys.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have irreplaceable data on this EC2 instance, it is *possible* to recover, but not easy. Here are some walkthroughs, which basically consist of one of the following:

- save the instance as an AMI, attach it to another instance
- modify CloudInit/userdata to add it on reboot

And here are the walkthroughs:

- [Alestic](https://alestic.com/2011/12/ec2-public-ssh-key/) - these instructions are from an AWS Hero
- [aws.amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598)
- [celingest](http://blog.celingest.com/en/2013/11/14/replace-lost-keypair-ec2-instance/)

Finally, **having such a valuable instance** (and making manual edits that destroy it) are good indications you aren't using good configuration management and 'cloud computing' principles. Any modern config management tool (chef, puppet, ansible, salt) can safely make changes to authorized_keys files. So would `vi`, though it's manual. Additionally, having a precious instance indicates you aren't heeding the "[cows](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2165267/cloud-computing/why-servers-should-be-seen-like-cows--not-puppies.html) [not](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/pets-vs-cattle) [puppies](http://www.computerweekly.com/blogs/cwdn/2013/04/treat-cloud-servers-like-cattle-not-puppies.html)" strategy. That would reduce the impact of a user-caused or random event affecting your life.

Comment: "Cows not puppies", awesome analogy.